# Google Apps Sites

Tags: web-hosting, g-suite

Is anybody using Sites available with Google Apps? I have a very small business and I just want to make a 3/4 pages website giving some information about who we are and what we do? I have purchased domain from GoDaddy and my email and other services are already running through Google Apps. I just wanted to know if the available Google Sites (part of the Google Apps Bundle) is good enough and does it support some sort of dynamic content  (like ASP/ASP.NET Hosting etc) or not?

Anybody having real experience with these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried it out some time ago. You can set up a site very quickly, but I found that the (layout/graphics) customization options are not very compelling: limited use of HTML and CSS  cannot be incorporated in theme templates. I found it also difficult to implement the same site in different languages (localization). I think Google sites could be okay for company-internal purposes (intranet, documentation etc.).

Originally a company called Jotspot developed the product, was targeted mainly at small-sized and medium-sized businesses. It basically is a structured wiki and primarily thought for static content. Simple dynamic content can be inserted using so called "Gadgets". See this tutorial: [Building Gadgets for Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/site/gsunhelp/step-by-step-guides/buildinggadgetsforgooglesites). Here is the [Gadget's API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/gadgets/docs/dev_guide.html).

You could find some background information on the [Google Sites Blog](http://googlesitesblog.blogspot.com/). This page, compiled by the groups community, contains a list of important things that are missing in the current version: [Things We Would Like Google to add/do to Google Sites](http://groups.google.com/group/sites-help/web/wishlist).

Answer (score 1):

Google Sites are **static** pages (mostly, I think you can integrate some dynamic functionality) that you can easily create using templates and populate using an online editor. I do believe they are a good option if you only have a simple "brochure" site that you need to publish without worrying about setting up hosting. Given that there is little investment in setting up a few pages, why don't you try? It is easy to upgrade at a later time if you need more features.

Google does also provide [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) that allows you to host web applications (Python, Java), but that's probably overkill for what you are describing.

If you want to set up a blog (WordPress), a CMS-based site (Drupal), a gallery, etc. you could have a look at someone like [Dreamhost Apps](http://www.dreamhostapps.com/), or similar payed plans, where you can host web applications. Do keep in mind that, while anyone can create a template site with Google Sites, you will need someone who knows what they're doing to customize WordPress for you.